# Composition of the a linear transformation to equal another linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm trying to solve this question:

> Consider a linear transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow
>  \mathbb{R}^2$ given by:
>
> $T(x,y) = (10x - 6y, -6x +10y)$
>
> Decide if exists or not a linear transformation $F: \mathbb{R}^2
>  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such as $F\circ F = T$ and justify it.

I have no idea how to start solving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$T=\begin{pmatrix} 10 & -6 \\ -6 &10 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$$
Note that $T$ is symmetric, so this means it will have real eigenvalues and can be diagonalized in an orthonormal basis.
$$T = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 1 &1  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 16 & 0 \\ 0 & 4  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 1 &1  \end{pmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 1 &1  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 4 & 0 \\ 0 & 2  \end{pmatrix}^2 \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 1 &1  \end{pmatrix}^{-1}$$
$$=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 1 &1  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 4 & 0 \\ 0 & 2  \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 1 &1  \end{pmatrix}^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 1 &1  \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 4 & 0 \\ 0 & 2  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 1 &1  \end{pmatrix}^{-1}$$